# Executing Remote PS to windows target from Ansible node

Tags: sql-server, ansible

I have the below playbook that I am trying to execute on a SQL Server node to trigger a Always on AG failover.

```
- name: Test Playbook
  hosts: win
  tasks:
    - name: test-execution
      win_shell: |
        Switch-SqlAvailabilityGroup -Path 'SQLSERVER:\Sql\<ServerName>\<InstanceName>\AvailabilityGroups\<AG-Name>'
```

However it errors out as follows

> fatal: []: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "Switch-SqlAvailabilityGroup -Path 'SQLSERVER:\Sql\\DEFAULT\AvailabilityGroups\'", "delta": "0:00:05.631889", "end": "2024-02-09 08:01:17.740381", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "start": "2024-02-09 08:01:12.108491", "stderr": "Switch-SqlAvailabilityGroup : Cannot find path \r\n'SQLSERVER:\Sql\\DEFAULT\AvailabilityGroups\' because it does not exist.\r\nAt line:1 char:65\r\n+ ... ing $false; Switch-SqlAvailabilityGroup -Path 'SQLSERVER:\Sql\ ...\r\n+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\r\n    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (SQLSERVER:\Sql\...\:String) [Switch-SqlAvailabilityGroup] \r\n   , ItemNotFoundException\r\n    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.Hadr.FailoverSqlAvailabilityGroup \r\n   Command", "stderr_lines": ["Switch-SqlAvailabilityGroup : Cannot find path ", "'SQLSERVER:\Sql\\DEFAULT\AvailabilityGroups\' because it does not exist.", "At line:1 char:65", "+ ... ing $false; Switch-SqlAvailabilityGroup -Path 'SQLSERVER:\Sql\ ...", "+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~", "    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (SQLSERVER:\Sql\...\:String) [Switch-SqlAvailabilityGroup] ", "   , ItemNotFoundException", "    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.Hadr.FailoverSqlAvailabilityGroup ", "   Command"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}

The PS command executes locally on the SQL Server node without any issues & triggers a failover. Just not able to get it to work from the Ansible controller.

I even tried the ignore_errors: true, but it didn't work as expected.